# Do you recognise this suspicious folder: Malicious or Benign

Tags: windows, security, malware

Does anyone recognise this suspicious folder that sits on my C drive?

The folder sits on my C drive at `C:\cacde6d0fd849a939328ab\` *The name obviously looks like a hash/encryption/or junk text.*

The folder has the following contents:
[image]

**Do you recognise these files and know if they are benign parts of windows or malicious program files?**

What makes me suspicious is that the folder and all its files are locked and cannot be deleted and because of the root folder name. I am aware that sometimes when Windows is uninstalling a program and the uninstallation is interupted that these kinds of folders can remain and have exe's in it by the name of `htstub.exe` (or something similar). Is this folder something similar, ie, benign?

Comment: Please, **DO NOT CROSS-POST**..... http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/40031/do-you-recognise-this-suspicious-folder-malicious-or-benign

Comment: You might not be able to delete them easily, but couldn't you hover over the Setup and the MSI (NPD40..) and determine what the item is?  Also shown is the "KB2840628" starting with KB like that usually indicates an update item, and using the whole number it is searchable on the web easily.  You could use that method at any time to get a fair idea as to what your looking at.  Then from there determine if it is consistant with a virus item or mostly looks like what it shows to be an update item.  Then hop into the updates and check the update history, and stuff to see if it "failed"

Comment: Yep, see 'em all the time. Leftovers from Windows Update. Pretty conclusive from the contents. That NDP40-KB2840628 is a massive clue. Google the KB number and you find plenty of results from Microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is either an uninstallation store for a windows update, or the temporary files left over after installing a windows update ([KB2840628](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2840628) a security update to .Net Framework 4). you can delete the folder, but that means it will be harder to uninstall the update in future.

Answer (score 0):

The folder is mostly likely left over from a windows update.  You need to go the security tab and "take ownership" of the folder. Then you can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Windows extracts the files from VC++ or .Net framework Updates to the drive with most free space. This is such an temporary folder which you can safely delete after you've installed the update.